# Sentence/Penalty On Crimes

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, usage

I have a question about the choice of the prepositions "*on*" and "*for*" [here](http://www.hoffmanlawoffice.com/differences-between-state-prison-and-county-jail.html):

> In comparison, State Prison is for inmates serving ***lengthier sentences on crimes*** that are more severe in nature.

Would replacing "*on*" with "*for*" be better?

Also in the following similar sentence:

> The penalty ***for/on*** robbery is severe.

Is either "*for*" or "*on*" more appropriate?

Comment: "On" looks like a strange choice of word.  I would normally say "for".  I see that the author is a lawyer or law firm; maybe it's legal terminology?

Answer (score 1):

For best grammar, I would re-write your first example sentence using *'for'* rather than *'on'*. I would also replace *'lengthier'* with *'longer'*. So the sentence should read:

> "In comparison, State Prison is for inmates serving longer sentences for crimes that are more severe in nature."

In your second example, good grammar would also indicate the use of *'for'* rather than *'on'*:

> "The penalty for robbery is severe."

Answer (score 1):

I would use the word 'for' for both examples. 
Using the word 'on' would seem more to refer to the subject matter of the following word such as "I gave a speech on drug abuse". Using the word 'for' is referring more to a consequence of an action, like in your case.

Answer (score 1):

In general, consequences -- including rewards and punishments -- are "for" their causes.

> In comparison, State Prison is for inmates serving lengthier sentences **for** crimes that are more severe in nature.

In the example the inmates are serving (the consequence) *for* their crimes (the cause).

However, there is a way that the less-common "on" might make sense. "Sentences" may also be considered legal language, and language is generally "on" (or about) a subject or topic. For example:

> - regulations **on** selling alcohol
> - restrictions **on** overtime

In this case, the language ("sentences") might be seen as controlling the topic ("crimes") and thus being "on" (or about) them in the general case, as in patterns or rules or norms for criminal sentencing:

> Justice Denman has been passing some very severe sentences **on** crimes of brutality in the Northern Circuit.
>
> It imposes longer sentences **on** crimes where women are targeted specifically.

These examples use "on," but "for" would also be grammatically correct. In these cases "on crimes" could also be read as: "on the occasion of crimes" or "when crimes occur." There is a slight difference in emphasis.

1. Sentences **on** crimes are being chosen as general policy in response to a category of event, with the type of crime as a topic (more impersonal, more abstract).
2. Sentences **for** crimes are being given to specific criminals as the consequences for their individual actions (more personal, more concrete).

For these reasons I would expect specific penalties to be *for*, not *on*:

> The penalty **for** robbery is severe.

However general policies would be *on* rather than *for*:

> The laws **on** robbery are complex.